# using entityFrameWork in windows service application gives the underlying providor failed to open error

Tags: c#, entity-framework

This is my service start code and my class. it is long but problem is just with database and entityFrameWork section please omit other lines. consider I just want to read a data from database:

my service start code:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread newThread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(ReadPolling.Read));
        newThread.Start();
    }
```

this is my ReadPolling.cs file:

```
public class ReadPolling
{
    public static webtccUsersEntities db;
    public static void Read()
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[1024];
            while (true)
            {
                    writeToDb(readBuffer);
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllText("D:\\1.txt", "read-write");
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText("D:\\1.txt", ex.Message);
        }

    }
    public static void writeToDb(byte[] userId)
    {
        db = new webtccUsersEntities();
        string _userId="";foreach(byte item in userId)
        {
            if(item!=0 || item!=40)
            _userId += (39 - item).ToString();
        }
        _userId = "0009544023";
        Time time;
        if(db.Times.Where(i=>i.userId==_userId).Count()>0)//User has at least one time
        {
            time = db.Times.Where(i => i.userId == _userId).OrderBy(i => i.dayDate).OrderBy(i=>i.inTime).Last();//last time

            if (time.dayDate == DateTime.Today)//today time
            { 
                if(time.outTime==null)//wants an out for today
                {
                    time.outTime = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();//an out for today
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                else//wants a new in/out for today
                {
                    Time newTime = new Time();newTime = db.Times.Create();  newTime.userId = _userId; newTime.dayDate = DateTime.Now.Date; newTime.inTime = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
                    db.Times.Add(newTime);db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            else//not today time
            {
                //new in for today
                Time newTime = new Time();newTime = db.Times.Create();newTime.dayDate = DateTime.Today;newTime.inTime = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();newTime.userId = _userId;
                db.Times.Add(newTime);db.SaveChanges();
            }

        }
        else//user first time
        {
            Time firstTime = new Time();
            firstTime = db.Times.Create();
            firstTime.userId = _userId;firstTime.dayDate = DateTime.Now.Date;firstTime.inTime = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
            db.Times.Add(firstTime);db.SaveChanges();
        }


    }
}
```

as you can see if an error occurs I write it to a file named "1.txt" in my drive "D:\". so when I start the service i open my text file and see the error "The underlying provider failed on Open.Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE'.".
what causes the problem?

Comment: Is there an inner exception?

Comment: @bolt19 yes, i added

Comment: @NeerPriv no. it is windows service, running in my computer :|

Comment: Ok i corrected it, it works :)

Answer (score 1):

You should log the inner exception as well as it indicates the actual connectivity error, which could be as simple as an invalid or missing connection string in your .config file...

Comment: altough your answer is not answer but it helped me to solve the problem. delete your answer and write it as a comment. thanks